# Django linkedin authentication programming error

Tags: django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

When I try to authenticate with linkedin in my django app, it passes the first stage where it asks me to give permission to linkedin to access my data, but fails to authenticate after that and displays this error.

[image: Django Debug page]

I have searched through the net and I have not seen anything on WSGIRequest.
This is my Linkedin authentication profile in my settings file

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = '7756p783kegdt2'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'irDH1gCxSJKICfhi'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = [
'email-address', 'headline', 'industry']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [
('id', 'id'),
('first-name', 'first_name'),
('last-name', 'last_name'),
('email-address', 'email_address'),
('industry', 'industry'),
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

This is my login urls being called in my settings file

```
LOGIN_URL = '/#authenticate'
LOGOUT_URL = '/user/logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

This is my view handling the user authentication

```
class CaseInsensitiveModelBackend(ModelBackend):
""" Allows Case insensitive Authentication for Username/emails """

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    """ confirm validity of username and password"""

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

This are my important urls

```
path(r'accounts/register', views.register, name='register'),
path(
    r'accounts/account-activation-sent/', views.account_activation_sent,
    name='account_activation_sent'
),
path(
    r'accounts/activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate,
    name='activate'
),
path(r'purchase/<token>/', views.purchase, name='purchase'),
path(r'<str:username>/deactivate/', views.deactivate, name='deactivate'),
path(r'deactivated/', views.deactivated, name='deactivated'),
path(r'accounts/login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
```

This is the url I want the user to be redirected to after authentication with linkedin

```
path(r'<str:username>/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `authenticate` is the request, not the username - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). You need to preserve that signature.

```
class CaseInsensitiveModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
```